# LINQ from DataTable Enumeration yielded no results

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following statement which when i run it i get

Enumeration yielded no results

```
 var striko4goodproduct = from myrow in GoodProduct.AsEnumerable()
                          where myrow.Field<string>("MachineID") == "Striko 4"
                          group myrow by myrow.Field<string>("MachineID") == "Striko 4" into g
                          select new
                          {
                            TotalGood = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int?>("VIngot") ??
                                                   0 + x.Field<int?>("Heads") ??
                                                   0 + x.Field<int?>("Risers") ?? 0)
                          };
```

Is it possible to have it return `0` instead of this message?

Sometimes there is going to be values in the database and other times there may not be.

I have tried to look at doing the following after it runs and assign a value to it.

```
if (striko4goodproduct.Equals(null))
{

}
```

Comment: Why do you use the anonymous type instead of simple `int`?

Comment: By the way, if `striko4goodproduct` was null, `striko4goodproduct.Equals` would throw an exception. You should always check for `striko4goodproduct == null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
int striko4goodProductCount = GoodProduct.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(r => r.Field<string>("MachineID") == "Striko 4")
  .Sum(r => (r.Field<int?>("VIngot") ?? 0) +
            (r.Field<int?>("Heads") ?? 0) + 
            (r.Field<int?>("Risers") ?? 0));
```

- Filtering by MachineID and then grouping by it will result in a single group - not very useful.
- [`+` has precedence over `??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx), so your code doesn't mean what it seems to mean. I've added parentheses to fix that.
- `striko4goodProductCount` should be of type `int`, and will be 0 when there are no values - that is the default of [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338442.aspx):

  > This method returns zero if source contains no elements.

Answer (score 3):

The `Enumeration yielded no results` is a debugger message, it's not something you would see at runtime so I wouldn't really concern myself with that.

Just check if the query has returned any results

```
if (striko4goodproduct.Any())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns the elements of the specified sequence or the specified value in a singleton collection if the sequence is empty.

So you're looking for something like (note that I removed the anonymous type):

```
var striko4goodproduct = (from myrow in GoodProduct.AsEnumerable()
                          ...).DefaultIfEmpty(0);
```

This way, if the inner query don't return a result, `DefaultIfEmpty` ensures that there's at least a single element (`0`).

---

Note that `if (striko4goodproduct.Equals(null))` will not work. A linq query will never return `null`; it will at least return an empty collection.

Comment: Doesn't that assume you have an `IEnumerable<int>`?

Comment: @Kobi Yes; I noted that I removed the anonymous type (which does not make sense to me, since it has only a single `int` property).

Comment: Getting a error with the above code "'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultIfEmpty' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: Note that you can't simply use `.DefaultIfEmpty(0)` because of your anonymous type, like I said in my answer and my comment above. If you wan't to keep using the anonymous type, use `DefaultIfEmpty(new { TotalGood = 0 })`.